# Return records from first ocurance one day to first occurance next day?

Tags: oracle

I have a very simple table that logs an event type (#1 through #9) with the timestamp and the shift (days-1,swing-2,grave-3) when it happened.  I would like to run a query that gives me all the events from the first day shift event on one date to the first day shift event the very next day.

something like:

```
select date_dt,event_type,shift 
  from my_table 
where *first occurance* shift#1 and date_dt = *some date*
to
select date_dt,event_type,shift 
    from my_table 
where *first occurance* shift#1 and date_dt = *the next day*`<code>
```

would this be some type of between statement or a union...  just not sure how to return a query that goes from the first event yesterday and stops at the first event today?

thanks for your help.

Chris

Comment: have your tried `between` for timestamp??

Answer (score 0):

You want the between operator

```
select date_dt,event_type,shift
from mytable
where date_dt between '19-DEC-2013' and 
    to_date('19-DEC-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

'19-DEC-2013'  is the first second of Dec 19, '19-DEC-2013 23:59:59' is the last second of that day.
As you expressed it you wanted no records from the next day, all possible records from just '19-DEC-2013' - the example date.

Comment: The problem is that graveyard starts on the 19th at 11:30pm and ends the next day the 20th at 5am. And then starts again later that night. I need to capture a 24 hour period starting on the 19th at 5am and ending on the 20th at 5am. The shifts vary from department so I wanted to capture from the start of shift 1 on the 19th to the start of shift 1 on the 20th. I'll try the between function some more. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table containing the expected start and end times for each shift:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2de76/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table ( date_dt,event_type,shift ) AS
          SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('20-Dec-13 03:23:17.010000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-19 Event 7', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('20-Dec-13 04:59:59.010000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-19 Event 8', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('20-Dec-13 05:30:17.010000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-19 Time Out', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('20-Dec-13 23:29:10.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-20 Time In', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('20-Dec-13 23:59:22.111100', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-20 Event 1', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('21-Dec-13 00:00:00.000000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-20 Event 2', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('21-Dec-13 02:17:23.333300', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-20 Event 3', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('21-Dec-13 04:30:10.444400', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-20 Event 4', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('21-Dec-13 05:01:07.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-20 Time Out', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('21-Dec-13 23:30:15.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-21 Time In', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('21-Dec-13 23:59:59.999999', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-21 Event 1', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('22-Dec-13 00:10:00.000000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-21 Event 2', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('22-Dec-13 01:11:11.111111', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-21 Event 3', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('22-Dec-13 04:45:45.454545', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '2013-12-21 Event 4', 'Security Shift 2' FROM DUAL;

-- Shift 2 is expected to start at 23:30:00 on the current day and finish at 05:00:00 on the next day.
CREATE TABLE shift_times ( shift, start_time, end_time ) AS
SELECT 'Security Shift 2', TO_DSINTERVAL( '0 23:30:00' ),  TO_DSINTERVAL( '1 5:00:00' ) FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Find the mid-point of the shift and subtract half-a-day
-- then shift the times so that the event times are an offset
-- from that time. This is used so that the "shifted times" for
-- each shift are all on the same day - even if a shift crosses
-- a day boundary.
WITH shifted_dates AS (
  SELECT date_dt - ( start_time + end_time )/2  + TO_DSINTERVAL( '0 12:00:00' ) AS shifted_date,
         date_dt,
         m.shift,
         event_type
  FROM   my_table m
         INNER JOIN
         shift_times s
         ON ( m.shift = s.shift )
  WHERE  m.shift = 'Security Shift 2'
),
-- Extract the year-month-day of the shift and conver it to a date.
days AS (
  SELECT TO_DATE( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM shifted_date )
                   || '-' || EXTRACT ( MONTH FROM shifted_date )
                   || '-' || EXTRACT ( DAY FROM shifted_date )
                 , 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) AS day,
         date_dt,
         shift,
         event_type
  FROM   shifted_dates
)
-- Select the events for the required day
-- plus the first event of the following day.
SELECT date_dt,
       shift,
       event_type
FROM   days
WHERE  day = TO_DATE( '2013-12-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN( date_dt    ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_dt ),
       MIN( shift      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_dt ),
       MIN( event_type ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_dt )
FROM   days
WHERE  day = TO_DATE( '2013-12-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
ORDER BY date_dt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2de76/2/0)**:

```
|                         DATE_DT |            SHIFT |          EVENT_TYPE |
|---------------------------------|------------------|---------------------|
| December, 20 2013 23:29:10+0000 | Security Shift 2 |  2013-12-20 Time In |
| December, 20 2013 23:59:22+0000 | Security Shift 2 |  2013-12-20 Event 1 |
| December, 21 2013 00:00:00+0000 | Security Shift 2 |  2013-12-20 Event 2 |
| December, 21 2013 02:17:23+0000 | Security Shift 2 |  2013-12-20 Event 3 |
| December, 21 2013 04:30:10+0000 | Security Shift 2 |  2013-12-20 Event 4 |
| December, 21 2013 05:01:07+0000 | Security Shift 2 | 2013-12-20 Time Out |
| December, 21 2013 23:30:15+0000 | Security Shift 2 |  2013-12-21 Time In |
```

If you don't have a table of shift start and end times then you can just pass that into the query as bind variables.